# Laravel route errror

Tags: php, laravel

I started using Laravel not that long ago and still feeling my way around it. Trying to create a simple user profile/edit profile using the framework. Got the code for the view from a git repo..Im also open to seeing other examples of profile/edit porifles as well!!

I got this error:

> Route [profile] not defined. (View:
> /var/www/html/swarzieapp/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php)

Route:

```
Route::post('profile/user/{username}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.user');
```

**Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProfileController extends Controller {



    /**      * /username     *   * @param $username      * @return Response      */     public function show($username)     {       $user = $this->getUserByUsername($username);

        return View::make('profile.profile')->withUser($user);  }

    /**      * /profiles/username/edit   *   * @param $username      * @return mixed     */     public function edit($username)     {       $user = $this->getUserByUsername($username);

        return View::make('profile.editpro')->withUser($user);  }

    /**      * Update a user's profile   *   * @param $username      * @return mixed     * @throws Laracasts\Validation\FormValidationException      */     public function update($username)   {       $user = $this->getUserByUsername($username);        $input = Input::only('location', 'bio', 'twitter_username', 'facebook_username', 'facebook_username');

        $this->profileForm->validate($input);

        $user->profile->fill($input)->save();

        return Redirect::route('profile.editpro', $user->username);     }

    /**      * Fetch user    * (You can extract this to repository method)  
*    * @param $username      * @return mixed     */      public function getUserByUsername($username)       {
            return User::with('profile')->where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();      }

**Profile.blade.php:**

    @extends('layouts/layout')
    
    @section('content')
        @if ($user->profile)
            <h1>{{ $user->username }} <small>{{ $user->profile->location }}</small></h1>
            <div class="bio">
                <p>
                    {{ $user->profile->bio }}
                </p>
            </div>
    
            <ul class="links">
                <li>{{ link_to('http://twitter.com/' . $user->profile->twitter_username, 'Find Me On Twitter') }}</li>
                <li>{{ link_to('http://facebook.com/' . $user->profile->facebook_username, 'Find Me On Facebook') }}</li>
          <li>{{ link_to('http://instagram.com/' . $user->profile->instagram_username, 'Find Me On Instagram') }}</li>
            </ul>
    
            @if ($user->isCurrent())
                {{ link_to_route('profile.edit', 'Edit Your Profile', $user->username) }}
            @endif
        @else
            <p>No profile yet.</p>
        @endif
    @stop
```

**Editpro.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts/layout')

@section('content')
    <h1>Edit Profile</h1>

    {{ Form::model($user->profile, ['method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => ['profile.update', $user->username]]) }}
        <!-- Location Field -->
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('location', 'Location:') }}
            {{ Form::text('location', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            {{ errors_for('location', $errors) }}
        </div>

        <!-- Bio Field -->
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('bio', 'Bio:') }}
            {{ Form::textarea('bio', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            {{ errors_for('bio', $errors) }}
        </div>

        <!-- Twitter_username Field -->
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('twitter_username', 'Twitter_username:') }}
            {{ Form::text('twitter_username', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            {{ errors_for('twitter_username', $errors) }}

        </div>

        <!-- Github_username Field -->
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('github_username', 'Github_username:') }}
            {{ Form::text('github_username', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
            {{ errors_for('github_username', $errors) }}
        </div>

        <!-- Update Profile Field -->
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::submit('Update Profile', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) }}
        </div>
    {{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

App.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>SWARZIE</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'SWARZIE') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('profile') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('profile').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Profile') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="profile" action="{{ route('profile') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>


                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help with this would help so very much :) <3

Comment: On which line you get the error

Comment: please add your app.blade.php from layouts directory

Comment: Sorry about that..will add the app.blade.php file later after work..so sorry

Comment: I added the app.blade.php

Answer (score -1):

the route for show should be (get) method

```
Route::get('profile/user/{username}', 'ProfileController@show')->name('profile.user');
```

Comment: **Route [profile] not defined.** means that there are no any name route called **profile**

Comment: It was originally 'get' but changed it..will check this out when I get off work..Thank ya!!!